# Fourier coefficients at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, fourier-series

Is there an obvious reason why Fourier coefficients of a given function cannot decay at infinity like, say, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$?
Why do they have to decay like integer powers of $\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: The Fourier coefficients of a function $f\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$ are in $\ell^2$, i.e., $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\hat{f}(n)|^2=\|f\|_2^2<\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason whatsoever, and it is not true that Fourier coefficients must decay like integer powers of $1/n$. In fact, given a sequence $c_k$ of positive real numbers that tends to zero,
there is a function $f\in L_1(0,2\pi)$
 such that $\hat{f}(k)\geq c_k$ for all $k\in\mathbb{ Z}$. In other words,
given any rate of decay, there is an integrable function on $(0,2\pi)$ whose Fourier coefficients have slower rate of decay.

If however you add some smoothness assumptions to $f$, such as--  $f$ is several times differentiable, then it is possible to prove that the Fourier coefficients have decay at a rate bounded by some polynomial rate of decay.

Comment: Ok, so say I have more regularity, like piecewise smoothness. Why do they have to be powers of integers then?

Comment: Well, they don't have to be exactly. All the estimates are inequalities, and being limited-scoped humans as we are, we find it convenient to compare growth-rates to integer powers. Usually we differentiate integer-number of times, so naturally comparisons are with integer powers. However, if you accept a notion of a fractional derivative, you will get fractional powers as rates of growth.

Comment: Wow, this is distressing. An exercise in my book, using the typical theorem $\mathcal{C}^k \leftrightarrow \sim \frac{1}{n^k}$, concludes that a piecewise smooth function with a jump discontinuity has fourier coefficients that decay like $\frac{1}{n}$. I guess it is wrong and all you can say is that it is at most like #\frac{1}{n}#?

Comment: I don't see why would anyone would be distressed to learn that some functions have Fourier coefficients decaying like $1/n$, and some **do not**.

Comment: Because it is expressed in that form. Piecewise smooth with jump discontinuity implies decay like $\frac{1}{n}$. Everytime, not just some.

Comment: Yes, and a differentiable function is continuous, every time. btw, in most cases, saying "decaying like" only means an inequality, an upper bound; it does not necessarily imply that all such functions decay precisely like $1/n$.

Comment: Piecewise smooth doesn't mean differentiable in the whole interval

Comment: We are not speaking the same language.

Comment: I don't understand why you wrote that a differentiable function is continuous every time.

Comment: $f\in L^2$ does not imply its Fourier coefficients decay polynomially at $\infty.$

Comment: @zhw - yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

For any function $f$ is bounded variation $|\hat {f} (n)| \leq \frac M n$ where $M$ is the total variation of $f$. [Ref. Fourier Series by Edwards].  Any piecewise differentiable function $f$ is of bounded variation.

Answer (score 0):

They can very well decay like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$.

Look at this

$$s_{\frac{1}{2}} = \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (k x)}{\sqrt{k}} = \frac{1}{2} i \left(\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(e^{-i x}\right)-\text{Li}_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)$$

which gives well defined function of $x$ in terms of polylog functions.

It is antisymmetric, has period $2 \pi$ and for $x \to +0$ it behaves as $x \zeta \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}}{\sqrt{x}}$

For more general decays we have

$$s_{p}=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin (k x)}{k^p}= \frac{1}{2} i \left(\text{Li}_p\left(e^{-i x}\right)-\text{Li}_p\left(e^{i x}\right)\right)$$

In this case we have for $x \to +0$

$$s_{p} \simeq x^{p-1} \cos \left(\frac{\pi  p}{2}\right) \Gamma (1-p)-\frac{1}{48} x^{p+2} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  p}{2}\right) \Gamma (4-p)+x \zeta (p-1)$$

Comment: Hi Wolfgang, I apologise but I was referring to a more regular context, say a piecewise smooth function on some interval, then extended by periodicity to the whole real line.

Answer (score 0):

The [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem)
 states that the average power of a signal equals the sum of the average power of its Fourier components.
$$
\eqalign{
  & f(t) = {{a_{\,0} } \over 2} + \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n} {a_{\,n} \cos \left( {nt} \right) + b_{\,n} \sin \left( {nt} \right)} \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad {1 \over {2\pi }}\int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f(t)^{\,2} dt}
  = \left( {{{a_{\,0} } \over 2}} \right)^{\,2}  + {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n} {\left( {a_{\,n} ^{\,2}  + b_{\,n} ^{\,2} } \right)}  \cr} 
$$

Thus, for a *finite power signal*, i.e. a  *phisycally possible signal*, the sum of the squares of its components must converge.
Clearly, if the amplitudes decay as $1/ \sqrt{n}$, the overall power won't be finite.